# What is a cognate enhancer sequence?

Tags: molecular-biology, gene-expression, terminology

What is a cognate enhancer sequence?

While reading a paper (1) presented at a journal class in graduate school, I encountered this sentence:

> HIF-1 binds to its cognate enhancer sequence, the hypoxia-responsive
>   element (HRE), and induces the expression of various genes related to the adaptation of cellular metabolism to hypoxia (the switch from oxidative to anoxic respiration),16 escaping from hypoxia (invasion and metastasis of cancer cells),17,18 improvements in hypoxia (angiogenesis)19,20 and the resistance
>   of malignant tumors to chemo as well as radiation therapy.

(1) Is [Wikipedia's definition of an enhancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhancer_(genetics)) correct for this case? Then does 'cognate' mean "related to, tending to be found together", whereas "sequence" means there's a chain reaction that occurs?

Y Zhu et al, "[Involvement of decreased hypoxia-inducible factor 1 activity and resultant G1–S cell cycle transition in radioresistance of perinecrotic tumor cells](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22710721)" Oncogene (2013) **32**, 2058–2068

Answer (score 3):

Cognate means *of common origin*.

In molecular biology, *cognate* is used to refer to known interacting pairs of functional entities. For example, *cognate receptor* of a ligand means the primary (default) receptor with which this ligand interacts. Similarly, *cognate sites* (which also includes enhancer) of a transcription factor (TF) refers to the well known and validated binding sites of the TF.

Also see [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/37121/3340) post.

Comment: I disagree. Cognate, as used in biological science, does **not** mean "of common origin", it just means **related**. See [my answer to a later question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59507/what-is-cognate-mirna/93670#936700).