# What is cognate miRNA?

Tags: genetics, microrna

I understand what miRNA are, but I'm unsure of what cognate means. Looking at this [post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/48556/what-is-a-cognate-enhancer-sequence), it seems that a cognate miRNA is a *known* miRNA vs. a recently discovered/possible miRNA. Is this thinking on the right track?

Answer (score 1):

The use of the word **cognate** in molecular biology reflects [adjectival definition 2 from Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/cognate):

2 *formal* **Related; connected.**
*‘cognate subjects such as physics and chemistry’*

The example given shows that this can be used in the most general sense of *related*, so that there is no requirement for some common antecedent as a surrogate for a human mother or ancestor.

Specifically there is **no** implication of the involvement of a common DNA sequence, as in the answer from @Dirigible, **nor** that of a *common origin* as invoked in [an earlier answer on this topic](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/48556/what-is-a-cognate-enhancer-sequence).

This is quite clear if one considers the much earlier usage of *cognate* in molecular biology in relation to an [mRNA codon and the tRNA anticodons](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/319/5865/878.2) that can recognize it, or a [tRNA and an aminoacyl tRNA synthetase](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21603/) that can aminoacylate it.

As far as the [usage with **microRNAs**](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms12200) is concerned, *a cognate mRNA is one with which the miRNA can interact* by base-pairing — no more, no less.